# Which mathematical or logical operations go behind &= in python?

Tags: python

I am learning python and I am stuck with this &= operator. I don't know what does it do. I searched on internet but nothing helped to get clear. Can somebody explain it with an example?

Comment: I can only assume this is a troll, as the simplest of searches suffices.

Comment: It's the in-place version of `&`: https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - refer this

Answer (score 1):

`&` is the bitwise `AND` operator.
`&=` is the bitwise `AND` equivalent of `+=`, `-=`, etc.

Basically, `a &= b` is shorthand for `a = a & b`.